# Skip insert query if a value is null Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert, null

Hi i have a table with different fields and i make an insert query and i want to skip the insert query if a value is null in one of the fields.
Example

```
Table
id    name    surname    kids
1     john      doe       2
2     mary      jones     3
```

and i want if the new insert has no value in the field kids to skip that entry.
is there a possible way to check that?`
the code i have is this

```
INSERT INTO `clients`.`kids` (`id`, `name`,`surname`,`kids`) VALUES (NULL,'".$data['name']."','".$data['surname']."','".$data['kids']."');";`
```

Comment: Please make `kids` field `NOT NULL` in DB

Comment: Try `if(!empty($data['kids'])){//your code}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a check -

```
if (!empty($data['kids'])) {
    // run the query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked to skip only if there is no Kids entered

```
if (!empty($data['kids'])) {
    //  query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check like This :

```
if(!empty($data['kids']) && isset($data['kids']))
 {
       // Write your code here 
 }
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong then Please Correct me. **!empty** itself check both conditions is variable set or not and is variable is not empty. So within your code does **isset** function make any difference